# MPI_Allgather receiving junk

Tags: fortran, mpi, openmpi

I have the following code:

```
              real          :: s_s, d_s, s_r(size), d_r(size)
              integer       :: k, k_r(size)

              ! - size = number of processors
              ! - Do something to initialise s_s, d_s, k
              write(*,*) "SENDING >>>>"
              write(*,*) s_s, d_s
              call MPI_Allgather( s_s, 1, MPI_REAL,
 &                 s_r, 1, MPI_REAL, MPI_COMM_PGM, mpi_err)

              call MPI_Allgather( d_s, 1, MPI_REAL,
 &                 d_r, 1, MPI_REAL, MPI_COMM_PGM, mpi_err)

              call MPI_Allgather ( k, 1, MPI_INTEGER,
 &                 k_r, 1, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_COMM_PGM, mpi_err)


              write(*,*) "RECEIVED <<<<"
              write(*,*) s_r, d_r, kr
```

This generates the following output:

```
SENDING >>>>
  -1803.80339864908       0.616157856320407     
 RECEIVED <<<<
  6.953077622513053E-310  3.565412685916647E-314  1.221334434576037E-314
  1.498827614035474E-314  6.952991536467244E-310  6.953288052096687E-310
  6.953108563966064E-310  2.350861403096908E-314           4           1
           2           3
```

kr is being gathered correctly however, s_r and d_r seem to be receiving junk. Could this be because of the MPI datatypes? I tried with `MPI_REAL` `MPI_REAL8` and `MPI_DOUBLE` but that didn't work. Furthermore, `mpi_err = MPI_SUCCESS`

What could I do to resolve this?

**EDIT 1**
I worked on the following prototype program:

```
program allgather
  implicit none

  include "mpif.h"

  real a(4)
  integer rank,size,ierr
  real as(4)
  real ar(16)
  integer i, j, k,z 

  a=1
  call MPI_INIT(ierr)
  call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierr)
  if(size.ne.4)then 
     write(*,*)'Error!:# of processors must be equal to 4'
     write(*,*)'Programm aborting....'
     call MPI_ABORT(ierr)
  endif

  do k=1,4
     if ( rank == (mod(k, size))) then
        a(k)  = k
     else
        a(k)  = 0.0 
     endif
  enddo

  write(*,*) "Rank :", rank
  write(*,*) a

  call MPI_Allgather(a, 4, MPI_REAL, ar,
 &     4,
 &     MPI_REAL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

  write(*,*) "Recieved array"
  write(*,*) ar

  do i = 1, 16
     if ( ar(i) /= 0.0 ) then
        z = mod(i, size)
        if ( z == 0 ) then
           a( size ) = ar(i)
        else
           a ( z ) = ar(i)
        endif
     endif
  enddo

  write(*,*) "---------"
  write(*,*) a
  write(*,*) "---------"

  call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
  end
```

And this generates the expected results i.e. `ar` doesn't gather junk. I'm unable to however tell the difference between the implementations.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your first block right now. Can you minimally change _that_ version (by setting some initial values for the values to pass) to be runnable while reproducing your issue? If you can't, odds are you removed something from your real code that is responsible for the bug.

Comment: One thing which is different is the communicator, I see that communicator `MPI_COMM_PGM` has been defined in another module. I use that module and specify the communicator in the code. A minimal example to reproduce the error would be quite verbose as this piece of code is embedded deep in a type bound method. Since it is sending the correct values, I presume there is an issue with only receiving.

Comment: In that case you're asking us to debug code we can't see.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, understood! Will upload a minimal code shortly

Comment: @AndrasDeak Indeed, the problem seems to be in another part of the code which controls buffer size. For now, I've solved the problem (see answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that for the project, the data type to be used was `MPI_FLT`. It is strange that `MPI_FLT` works and not `MPI_REALx` where x=4,8 also not `MPI_FLOAT`. I grep-ed `MPI_FLT` in the project to see what it is defined as but didn't turn up anywhere in the project.

The OpenMPI version I'm using is:

```
$ mpirun --version
mpirun (Open MPI) 3.0.0
```

The compiler I use is:

```
$ mpifort --version
ifort (IFORT) 19.0.1.144 20181018
```

In a future edit I will elaborate on the cause.